# child process receives SIGINT which should be handled only by parent process, resulting in abrupt termination of child

Tags: go, signals, stdout

I am trying to manage an application (which needs to be closed with a certain procedure, in this case saving the world) in golang using stdpipes.
This is a bare-bone example of what I'm trying to achieve but I have a problem which is quite specific for me but it might be interesting also for others (maybe you can suggest how to generalize it).

I also added a function called `interruptListener` that creates a goroutine and manages the stop of the program when a kill signal is sent

**Normal function of the script**:

- launch the minecraft server
- waits 40 seconds and then issues through stdIn the "stop" command
  (in this case it works as expected printing all the logs about the saving process)

**Test case** (to demonstrate where is the problem):

- launch the minecraft server
- before the script issues the stop command the user send ctrl+c
  (in this case it should finish printing the logs about the saving process and then exit, but it does not... it seems that after receiving the kill signal the `scanner.Scan()` returns false so it just exits)

Do you have an idea of why this could be happening? what should I research to get to the solution?

I'm really lost I already spent 8+ hours with all the possible combination of codes...

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "os/signal"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

var cmd *exec.Cmd

var wg sync.WaitGroup

var stdOut io.ReadCloser
var stdErr io.ReadCloser
var stdIn io.WriteCloser

func main() {
    interruptListener()

    cSplit := strings.Split("java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar server.jar nogui", " ")
    cmd = exec.Command(cSplit[0], cSplit[1:]...)
    cmd.Dir = "path/to/server/folder"
    stdOut, _ = cmd.StdoutPipe()
    stdErr, _ = cmd.StderrPipe()
    stdIn, _ = cmd.StdinPipe()
    wg.Add(2)
    go printer(stdOut)
    go printer(stdErr)
    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    // test 1: wait 40 seconds for it to send the stop command and observe the output
    // test 2: in the 40 seconds (after the server has loaded press ctrl+c), there is no output
    time.Sleep(40 * time.Second)
    execute("stop")

    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
}

func printer(stdP io.ReadCloser) {
    defer func() {
        wg.Done()
        fmt.Println("printer is out")
    }()

    var line string

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(stdP)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        line = scanner.Text()

        fmt.Println(line)
    }

    fmt.Printf("scanner error: %v\n", scanner.Err())
}

func execute(com string) {
    fmt.Println("sending", com, "to terminal")

    // needs to be added otherwise the virtual "enter" button is not pressed
    com += "\n"

    // write to cmd
    _, err := stdIn.Write([]byte(com))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }
}

func interruptListener() {
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, syscall.SIGHUP, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGQUIT)
    go func() {
        select {
        case <-c:
            execute("stop")
            wg.Wait()
            os.Exit(0)
        }
    }()
}
```

Comment: Just to catch any possibly related errors:  You cannot call `wg.Add` from within the goroutine itself, you should defer the `wg.Done()`, you're not checking the error from the scanner, and you're not waiting on the child process so you don't when or why that is exiting.

Comment: thanks @JimB I updated the code following your suggestions, but still I am unable to find an error and the behavior is the same as before... Do you have some other suggestions? thanks

Comment: Are you certain the command isn’t exiting immediately? The terminal is probably sending the signal to the whole process group

Comment: Going off what @JimB said, have you tried changing `exec.Cmd.SysProcAttr.Setpgid` to true for starting the managed process? https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#SysProcAttr

Comment: Note that SIGINT can also cause an output flush (this is very timing-dependent and also probably OS-dependent).

Comment: @JimB I think this is the case, where the SIGINT is received by the main process and the child process...

Comment: @TylerKropp on windows I am unable to set the `Setpigd` parameter, do you know of any other way? what `Setpigd` would do in my case?

Comment: @torek do you know of any way to sort of "catch" the signal avoiding it to reach the child process?

Comment: @raelene: you can try adding `syscall.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP` to `SysProcAttr.CreationFlags` on windows

Comment: @raelene: on linux the equivalent would be `Setpgid` as mentioned above. These will require different source files with appropriate build constraints.

Comment: Yes indeed (just tested it on a linux VM) @JimB @TylerKropp and I guess the `Setpgid` would work also for the darwin architecture?

Comment: Using setpgid works on all POSIX-y systems, but you might still have an output flush due to the signal (depending on tty driver and timing vagaries). The usual way to avoid that is to put the terminal into CBREAK mode and remove all signaling control characters, via POSIX "termios". This moves all responsibility for input handling to your process, so then you have to take over everything, which can be tricky: you need to know when to distribute signals to the pgroup, for instance.

Comment: This kind of thing is generally rather fraught. If you can avoid the situation entirely (with a system redesign), that might be better.

Comment: @torek thank you very much for the explanation! do you have a suggestion for a system redesign? any hint for a direction? (I'm kinda lost ahah...)

Comment: Not really - I have no idea what you're trying to do here. :-) (I've seen people play minecraft, but don't know what you're doing with the server.)

Comment: ok thank you a lot anyway! (my example is with minecraft but any program whose termination requires a specific procedure applies here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks to the people that answered in the comments this is an acceptable solution (still not perfect as explained in the comments)

just add this few lines before executing `cmd.Start()`:

```
    // launch as new process group so that signals (ex: SIGINT) are not sent also the the child process
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
        CreationFlags: syscall.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP, // windows
        // Setpgid: true, // linux
    }
```

Comment: Here's a source that has a reasonable explanation for how and why this works, see the section on process groups - https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-10.html

Answer (score -1):

Here's a more complete answer to your question - [Killing a child process and all of its children in Go](https://medium.com/@felixge/killing-a-child-process-and-all-of-its-children-in-go-54079af94773#id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImMzMTA0YzY4OGMxNWU2YjhlNThlNjdhMzI4NzgwOTUyYjIxNzQwMTciLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.H6_Tfrtn5J19WVDPWd7-nE8LSu7Ps4ZP9w7ys03jyIH3V5a8eTb96NOZS2P7XVwhryNdwqmSMEGT7W7rs2sBXWCcG9r054GVrBPFtheH0h4bblrzf8K474DAmY5QvPHl6khTpvjC_lK8z6v6bTxWiMk5lEqebqLpEoYWHa2pIdg5YSEPDyHvck9yNPgNQ-YfJxqGF0ENU42kBewvY2Ss7HoA7nF1qtW6p4xlfiQbgCDVoPireqLCqYoU86EhBsZwkZ7sGqiLWZ8vZ5Mw4HJ6m6RDZtrUZbJndjQehvXYyomGs40F09o5k8EdehMHnbmqlP15ZP3awZ7Na9dwNTi20A)